# Date value not showing in the calendar with HTML5 support in VS2012

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

I have a Form View has a text field in the , the text field binded to a 2 way binded control, code as follow:

```
<td class="table-4">
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.DOB%>' TextMode="Date" Width="200px"</asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

and I'm using TextMode as Date which will result in displaying the calender in the browser.

in the Model Entity class I'm defining the DOB as:

```
<Display(Name:="Date of Birth"), DataType(DataType.DateTime), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")> _
Public Property DOB() As Date?
```

**The problem:**
When using Google Chrome or Opera which they are excellent in handling & compatible with HTML5 elements, the txtDOB field doesn't show the date data value which binded from the db, what displayed instead is:
1- in Chrome, displays yyyy-mm-dd, which is the date format iam using
2- in Opera, the txtbox is empty.

Both browsers displays the calendar when clicked on the field.

Why the bounded date data not shown in the text field also not marked/selected when the calendar opened?

**Note:** in IE I see it as normat txtField with the date value binded from the db, of course no calendar view coz IE ver 9 doesn't support fully HTML5 which results to not understand the tag (TextMode="Date")

**Used technology:**
- VS 2012 
- Entity Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set format to ISO date format:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ... Text='<%# Bind("BirthDate","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'v already added this line & it works fine Bind("BirthDate","{0:d}"). Sorry I didn't update my question as answered before. Thanks for the help